# Superset & Prophet (Forecast) not working

Tags: apache-superset, facebook-prophet

I am using Superset v1.5.1, and trying to use the Forecast option. I ran multiple commands, including:

```
pip --no-cache-dir install pystan==2.19.1.1 && pip install prophet
```

or

```
pip install lunarcalendar tqdm "pystan<3.0" && pip install "prophet>=1.0.1, <1.1"
```

in my Superset container, but still, when I try to use Forecast, it doesn't work.

The error Superset shows is the following:

```
No results were returned for this query
```

as seen here [image: Superset Prophet not working picture]

The strange part is that, whenever I don't use it, it works just fine, but the moment I turn on the Forecast, it just gives me 0 rows results and done. I guess it comes from Prophet, but I can't seem to figure out what is missing.
No matter what parameters, or data I give, it just returns 0 rows, every time.

No logs in Superset, install works fine.
Using Druid SQL to query Druid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem until I made sure to install `prophet` not `fbprophet`. My guess is that one of your dependencies is missing or wrong, running prophet by itself should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

[Here in github](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/20901) it was solved - dependencies were messed up:

> **@ecederstrand:** Preinstalling lunarcalendar, tqdm and pystan is necessary because prophet <= 1.0 has a bug that requires these packages to be available when running setup.py to build the package. This was fixed in prophet 1.1 but that version can't be installed along with superset 2.0 due to a version conflict on the holidays package. I just contributed a fix for that conflict in #21091.

In short, add this to your Dockerfile for Superset:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install lunarcalendar tqdm "pystan<3.0" && pip install > "prophet>=1.0.1, <1.1"
```

And it will work.

Comment: The solution indeed works, but you have a typo in the second command (redundant ">"). This is the correct one: `RUN pip install lunarcalendar tqdm "pystan<3.0" && pip install "prophet>=1.0.1, <1.1"`